# How to monitor all Cores CPU usage on AWS machine

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cpu

I have a AWS machine with 8 core CPU. I want to get the all core CPU usage with MAX/average for all 8 cores individually at a time. AWS also provides CPU usages under Monitoring tab but that seems the average of all cores.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install and configure [CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) on your instance to monitor what you want.